# How to add repositories which require authentication in sbt project

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Getting help from [this site](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-configure-sbt-custom-repositories-resolvers), I have put something like that in my `build.sbt` file to be able to access some private Maven repositories. However, these repositories also require a username and password for authentication. How can I add that here?

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
   "PrivateRepo1" at "http://privaterepo1/releases/",
   "PrivateRepo2" at "http://privaterepo2/maven/2/"
)
```

I even tried to add this above, but still couldn't make it work.

```
credentials += Credentials("PrivateRepo1", 
  "http://privaterepo1/releases/", "<uname>", "<password>")
credentials += Credentials("PrivateRepo2", 
  "http://privaterepo2/maven/2/", "<uname>", "<password>")
```

Note that these private repositories are hosted on [Nexus repository manager](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the credentials, you should specify only the host:

```scala
credentials += Credentials(
  "PrivateRepo1", 
  "privaterepo1.com",
  "<uname>",
  "<password>"
)
```

unrelated, avoid specifying the credentials in the code.
you can read the credentials from environment variables for example

```scala
credentials += Credentials(
  "PrivateRepo1", 
  "privaterepo1.com",
  sys.env.getOrElse("private_repo_user", "Unknown"),
  sys.env.getOrElse("private_repo_pass", "Unknown")
)
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried only the host, but it still didn't work. Doesn't help that the repository works on a specific port. So I also tried privaterepo1.com:portnumber, but it still didn't work.

Comment: you shouldn't put the ip. is your realm correct? e.g "Sonatype Nexus" or "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"?

Comment: Maybe its the fault of realm. I will check that.